# why is data not inserted in mysql database no error comes on the screen?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I make a author_create_post.php for a News Agency Portal and Insert the data entries into mysql database. php script and form relies on same page. Form also used validation rules. After fill all form entries finally when I hit submit I got no any error but when I checked my database there is no insert entry, what is the problemb? How to solve it? Here is my complete code...

```
<?php
include "../tools/db.php";
include "../tools/functions.php";
include "../tools/jdf.php";
FetchPage("check_permission.php");
Permission("author");
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
    if($_POST["title"]!="" && $_POST["text"]!="" && $_POST["category"]!="" && $_POST["slider"]!="" && $_POST["important"]!=""){
        $title = ($_POST["title"]);
        $text = addslashes($_POST["text"]);
        $date = jdate('c');
        $time = time();
        $author_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        $cat_id=($_POST["category"]);
        $slider=($_POST["slider"]);
        $important=($_POST["important"]);

            switch($cat_id){
                case 0: 
                    $cat_id = 0;
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    $cat_id = 1;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    $cat_id = 2;
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    $cat_id = 3;
                    break;
                default :
                    $cat_id = 4;    
            }
            $s = "SELECT `title` FROM `$tbl_posts` WHERE `title`=:title";
            $res = $connect->prepare($s);
            $res->bindParam(":title",$title);
            $res->execute();
            if($res->rowCount()>=1){
                $exist ="عنوان پست تکراری می باشد!";
        }else{
            $r = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `$tbl_posts` WHERE `important`=1");
            if($r->rowCount()>=5){
                $imp_count = "درحال حاضر بخش اخبار مهم تکمیل میباشد حداکثر ظرفیت این بخش 4 خبر است!";
            }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tbl_posts` ( `author_id`, `title`, `category_id`, `time`, `text`, `date`, `slider`, `important` ) VALUES ( :author_id, :title, :category_id, :time, :text, :date, :slider, :important )";
            $result = $connect->prepare($sql);
            $result->execute( array(':author_id'=>$author_id, ':title'=>$title, ':category_id'=>$cat_id, ':time'=>$time, ':text'=>$text, ':date'=>$date, ':slider'=>$slider, ':important'=>$important));
            if(isset($result)){
                $success =" پست ".$title." در سایت منتشر شد ✓ ";
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('Wrong!');</script>";
            }
        }
    }
    }else{
        if($_POST["title"]=="") $titleerr = "عنوان مطلب را درج نمایید!";
        if($_POST["text"]=="") $texterr = "متن پست خالی میباشد!";

    }
}   
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="mahdi">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.20script.ir/img/website.js"></script>
    <meta name="keyword" content="FlatLab, Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.html">

    <title>ارسال مطلب جدید</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 tooltipss and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="editor/nicEdit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });</script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" class="">
      <!--header start-->
        <?php FetchPage("top.php"); ?>
      <!--header end-->

      <!--sidebar start-->
      <aside>
        <?php FetchPage("right.php"); ?>
      </aside>
      <!--sidebar end-->
      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
            <section class="wrapper">
                <!-- page start-->
                <div class="row">
                    <aside class="profile-info col-lg-9">
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($success) && $success!=""){ 
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                            <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
                                <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                            </button>
                            <center><strong>تبریک ! </strong><?=$success;?></center>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php 
                            if(isset($titleerr) && $titleerr!=""){ 
                        ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                                <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
                                    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                                </button>
                                <center><strong>اخطار ! </strong> <?=$titleerr;?></center>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php 
                            if(isset($imp_count) && $imp_count!=""){ 
                        ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                                <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
                                    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                                </button>
                                <center><strong>اخطار ! </strong> <?=$imp_count;?></center>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php 
                            if(isset($texterr) && $texterr!=""){ 
                        ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                                <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
                                    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                                </button>
                                <center><strong>اخطار ! </strong> <?=$texterr;?></center>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <section class="panel">
                            <div class="bio-graph-heading">ارسال مطلب جدید</div>
                            <div class="panel-body bio-graph-info">
                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">عنوان مطلب</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 620px;" name="title" placeholder=" ">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">متن پست</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <textarea name = "text" style="width: 620px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">دسته بندی</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <select name="category">
                                                <?php
                                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$tbl_category` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
                                                $result = $connect->query($sql);
                                                while($rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                                ?>
                                                <option value="<?=$rows["id"];?>"><?=$rows["title"];?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">نمایش در اسلایدر</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <select name="slider">
                                                <option value="0">غیرفعال</option>
                                                <option value="1">فعال</option>         
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                  

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">نمایش در اخبار مهم</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <select name="important">
                                                <option value="0">غیرفعال</option>
                                                <option value="1">فعال</option>         
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                            <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-success" value="ثبت">
                                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">انصراف</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </aside>
                </div>

                <!-- page end-->
            </section>
        </section>
        <!--main content end-->
    </section>

    <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.sparkline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.customSelect.min.js" ></script>

    <!--common script for all pages-->
    <script src="js/common-scripts.js"></script>

    <!--script for this page-->
    <script src="js/sparkline-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/easy-pie-chart.js"></script>

  <script>

      //owl carousel

      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
              navigation : true,
              slideSpeed : 300,
              paginationSpeed : 400,
              singleItem : true

          });
      });

      //custom select box

      $(function(){
          $('select.styled').customSelect();
      });

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please break your code into more blocks and write what you tried already https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for debugging purposes try echo-ing the query and inserting it manually into the db. You will find your error

Comment: is `$tbl_post` actually a defined variable for the table?

Comment: No error, right; well you should have gotten one about an undefined variable.

Comment: and what about `$tbl_category`; where is that defined? you will be responding to comments, right? Or are you the silent type?

Comment: your code contains too many errors and unknowns. One of which being `#owl-demo` and the ID for it in the HTML.

Comment: seems OP is MIA

Comment: Being silent/ignoring comments isn't polite. If you left the question, then you'll need to take it up with the answer given below. If it doesn't work, tough luck. Comments were given asking for clarification; it's like pulling teeth.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$tbl_posts` ( `author_id`, `title`, `category_id`, `time`, `text`, `date`, `slider`, `important` ) VALUES ( :author_id, :title, :category_id, :time, :text, :date, :slider, :important )";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_posts` ( `author_id`, `title`, `category_id`, `time`, `text`, `date`, `slider`, `important` ) VALUES ( :author_id, :title, :category_id, :time, :text, :date, :slider, :important )";
```

You had a `$` sign before your table name

Also when verifying the success or failure of the execute function, do this

```
    if ($result === true) {
        $success =" پست ".$title." در سایت منتشر شد ✓ ";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong!');</script>";
    }
```

isset does not verify that the query was successfully executed. And remember `execute()` returns true or false So you need to check based on the boolean values(true or false)

Comment: Dear Akin
I define $tbl_posts in db.php 

$tbl_posts = "tbl_posts";